# Make Aptana never use Windows line endings

Tags: aptana

Is there a way to configure Aptana so that it always uses Unix line feeds instead of Windows line feeds?

Answer (score 30):

You can change this setting by going into "Window" >"Preferences" > "General" > "Workspace" and change the "New text file line delimiter" from "Default" to "Other" and then select "Unix" in the drop-down menu.

Comment: Does this however also apply to existing files? I think the original asked wanted to how to also automatically convert existing files with Windows line endings to use Unix line endings.

Answer (score 15):

Try "File" > "Convert Line Delimiters To" > "{choose platform}" ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you have existing files you want to switch to unix line endings, use `dos2unix`:

```
dos2unix my_file_edited_on_crappy_windows.txt
```