# Why there is additional unwanted line in my php file when it has uploaded to cpanel?

Tags: php, aptana, cpanel, filezilla

I've been searching in google for this, but I did not find an answer. or maybe I do not know a good keyword for this. I always find my files have unwanted new line every time I uploaded to cpanel.

**Before Upload:**
[image: before upload to cpanel]
**After Upload:**
[image]

It started when I uploaded myfile.php with **208 lines** today via FileZilla, and the next day I re-download the file and I edited using Aptana. suddenly i got the file already has the unwanted new line become **382 lines**. Are you have been experiencing with this? please help me solve this problem. Thank you. Sorry for bad english

Comment: what are the new lines having .... ?

Comment: @user1844933 new lines is just blank like my images

Comment: @NoobEditor i don't know because the server is share hosted. How the check it? what is the relationship between that module & my files?

Comment: @dian : i deleted my comment because later i realised that the page-speed changes the run-time code on browser, not the original source code...apologies!!!!

Comment: @NoobEditor oh ya never mind, btw i am using windows 7 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the conversion of file between different operating systems.

The server is a unix system, which changes the line termination character.  As such when the files is downloaded from the server, you need to use a utility like `unix2dos` to convert the file.

Comment: i tend to disagree..i have uploaded files from windows to unix server but never faced this issue...is there some other trait for this?

Comment: @NoobEditor This is a quite common issue, to a point that `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` commands exist in most unix system just to sidestep this issue. see - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Common_problems

Comment: i have no problem on the same day, when i redownload the file in same day, it has no problem. but when i redownload the file in the next day. The unwanted new line is appear and make a mess of my file :(

Comment: @dian Most Development Environments support unix and dos new lines.  What Development Environment are you using?

Comment: @kami i don't understand about Development Environments that you said :D I am using Aptana, is it make sense?

Comment: @dian See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318075/make-aptana-never-use-windows-line-endings

Comment: to method of identifying where,  @see comments to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593326/unwanted-new-line-returned-after-ajax-request/11593384#11593384